# Parsing with Bison: constructor in action

Tags: c++, parsing, bison, flex-lexer

I am trying to construct a parser with Bison. I have the following in the first section:

```
%union {
    int ttype;
    // enums used in lexer
    Staff stafftype;
    Numeral numeral;
    Quality quality;
    Inversion inversion;
    Pitch pitch;
    Accidental accidental;
    // Classes used in parser
    Roman roman;
}

%token <stafftype> STAFFTYPE
%token <numeral> NUMERAL
%token <quality> QUALITY
%token <inversion> INVERSION
%token <pitch> PITCH
%token <accidental> ACCIDENTAL
%token <ttype> COLON
%token <ttype> SLASH
%token <ttype> COMMA

%type <roman> accidentalRoman
```

With some grammar rules. Here is one:

```
accidentalRoman
    : NUMERAL { $$ = Roman($1); }
    | ACCIDENTAL NUMERAL { $$ = Roman($2, $1); }
    ;
```

I basically have three related questions.

1. What does the %union *really* represent? I thought it represented types the lexer could return. My lexer rules contain statements like `return STAFFTYPE`, to indicate that I have populated `yylval.stafftype` with a `Staff` object. Fair enough. However;
2. the union also seems to have something to do with the `$$ =` statements in the grammar actions. Why do the result types of grammar actions need to be in the union?
3. In my example, the `Roman` class has a constructor with parameters. However, declaration in the union causes the error `no matching function for call to 'Roman::Roman()'`. Is there any way around this? I'm trying to build up a parse tree with `$$ =`, and the nodes in the tree definitely need parameters in their constructors. In fact, it doesn't even allow a 0-parameter constructor: `error: union member 'YYSTYPE::roman' with non-trivial 'Roman::Roman().`

Comment: It's years ago I used bison. As I know it, yacc/bison generates C code out of your y file. Please, have a look into it - it may help you to understand what happens "under the hood". You should find a `union` which contains exactly what `%union` provides. `union` (in C++) and classes do not work well together (due to the construction issue). It may work under some restrictions but I prefer to prevent this completely.

Comment: The `%union` is used to attribute rules. Whenever, there is extra data which has to be passed for a token (flex) or a rule (bison), `%union` comes into play. That was OK in C but may cause conflicts if you want to use it in C++. (Sorry, I start to repeat me.) A work around could be, to use global variables (may be even stacks) instead of attributes (crafted with `%union`). For me, it was one reason to stop the usage of bison (and making recursive descent parsers instead. Btw. debugging and maintenance was the main reason...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. What does the `%union` really represent? I thought it represented types the lexer could return.

No. It represents types that *productions* can return, via `$$ =`. The lexer just returns integer constants defined via `%token` directives. The lexer can populate a `yylval` member *as a side effect,* but it isn't a return type of the lexer in any sense.

> My lexer rules contain statements like return STAFFTYPE, to indicate that I have populated yylval.stafftype with a Staff object.

They shouldn't. They should return token types as used in the grammar, and you shouldn't usually have put anything into `yylval` except in the case of literals. You're doing work in the lexer that the parser should do.

> 2. the union also seems to have something to do with the `$$ = statements` in the grammar actions. Why do the result types of grammar actions need to be in the union?

Because that's where they are placed. On top of the stack of `yylval` values.

> 3. In my example, the Roman class has a constructor with parameters. However, declaration in the union causes the error no matching function for call to 'Roman::Roman()'. Is there any way around this? I'm trying to build up a parse tree with `$$ =`, and the nodes in the tree definitely need parameters in their constructors. In fact, it doesn't even allow a 0-parameter constructor: error: union member `YYSTYPE::roman` with non-trivial `Roman::Roman()`.

In general the`%union` should consist of ints, doubles, other primitive types, and *pointers.* Objects in unions are problematic anyway, and on a parser stack are mostly a massive waste of space.